# React component returns empty doing foreach on JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON object with multiple leves that I'm trying to iterate through to display like this, but I keep getting empty results.

```
<div>    
Operation
    **Speed: Slow
    **Direction: Forward
    **Status: Moving
</div>
<div>
Detail
**Type: Electric
**Drivetrain: AWD
</div>
```

JSON object

```
    "operation": {
        "speed": "slow",
        "direction": "forward",
        "status": "moving"
      },
  "detail": {
    "type": "electric",
    "drivetrain": "AWD"
  }
```

The following works, but difficult to wrap each level in a DIV

```
    const Bompush = (obj) => {
        let output = []

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            output.push(<div key={key}>{key}</div>)

            Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach (value => {
                output.push(<div key={value}>{value}</div>)

            })
        })

        return output  
}
```

This is the ideal way I'd like to do this but it returns empty

```
const Bom = (obj) => {
 return (
    <div className="outerContainer">
        {
            Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, item) => { 
                return (
                    <div className="category" key={key}>{key}
                        {                        
                        Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach (value => { 
                            return (<div className="item" key={value}>{value}</div>); 
                        })
                        }
                    </div>
                );
            })
        }
    </div>
  );  

 }
```

My React component

```
  export default class DiplayBom extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
        Bom(this.props.myValues)
        )
    }


  }
```

Comment: forEach doesn't return anything, I think you want to use map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't collect the results. You want `map`:

```
Object.keys(obj[key]).map(value => (
  <div className="item" key={value}>{value}</div>
))
```

You'd be better off pulling out the inner component (at the very least), because as simple as this is, it's already pretty hard to read. I'd consider restructuring the object, plus you're at the mercy of object property ordering, so you may not always get the results you'd prefer.

There's some refactoring and/or rethinking to be done.

---

Without deviating much from your original code, and completely untested, I'd probably start thinking more along these lines:

```
const Item = ({ value, item }) => (
  <div className="item">{value}: {item}</div>
)

const Category = ({ cat, obj }) => {
  return (
    <div className="category">
      {key}

      {Object.keys(obj).map(val => <Item key={val} value={val} item={obj[val]} />)}
    </div>
  )
}

const Bom = obj => (
  <div className="outerContainer">
    {Object.keys(obj).map(cat => <Category key={cat} cat={cat} obj={obj[cat]} />)}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: That works!  My object is defined coming out of React Final Form so I'm stuck with it.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ryatkins You're such with the object, but you're not stuck on how you choose to process that object.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on making this cleaner :)  I don't like how unreadable it is either.

Comment: @ryatkins (*Very*) Roughly I'd start moving towards something like what I appended to the answer. I'd also probably use a polyfill or utility for mapping objects so you don't have to deal with `Object.keys`. Without knowing more that's about the best I can do for now.

Comment: Made an update to add cat={cat} as React didn't like passing a variable through key.  Also, Item now received both the key value pair at that level.  Thanks again Dave.